# custom listview shows large space between them when adding a new item by clicking on button in android studio

Tags: android, listview

[image]

I have got a custom listview. I am trying to add items to the custom listview by clicking on the button. When I click the button, I want the items to show one under the other but it shows a big space between items.  Data read from the database are listed in the listview at the same time.it works like chat applications. Thanks for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"


    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Mainactivity">




    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listid"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@drawable/dessen"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lineerid"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>






    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineerid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="#91f1f1f1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mesajid"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gonderid"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxHeight="80dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gonderid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonsekil"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Gönder" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom _layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nickid"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#352925"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">


        </TextView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tarihid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#352925"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">


        </TextView>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formesajid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#050505"
            android:textColorLink="#9C27B0"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">


        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

custom adapter

```
public class customadapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private List<Model> modelList;
public customadapter(Activity activity,List<Model> modelList) {

layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

this.modelList=modelList;
}


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return modelList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
        TextView nick =view.findViewById(R.id.nickid);
        TextView tarih=view.findViewById(R.id.tarihid);
        TextView mesaj=view.findViewById(R.id.formesajid);
        Model model=modelList.get(position);

nick.setText(model.getNickname());
tarih.setText(model.getTarih());
mesaj.setText(model.getMesaj());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share `dessen.xml`?

Comment: it is png not XML.  The problem was still there before I added it.

Comment: I checked your layout and item layout without divider it seems fine. You can try divider parameter like `android:divider="?dividerHorizontal"` and check if there is a big space or not.

Comment: I don't think the problem with the divider cause I tried all of them. when I refresh the activity, all items show orderly. when clicking the button, items add the end of listview but items added first shows  on top .

Comment: Can you share your adapter code and also the code how you add new item?

Comment: Adapter seems fine. One more thing can you share button click function?